# Variable assignment into if statement for example

Tags: php, operator-precedence

I'm a bit confused about operator precedence actually.

> Here is an example that doesn't match with the [php official website](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

```
 function getValue($key) {
      $array = ['un' => 1, 'six' => 6];

      if (array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
           return $array[$key];
      }

      return null;
 }

 var_dump(null === $t1=getValue('un'));
 var_dump(null === $t2=getValue('blablablaaaaaa'));
 // And now I switch
 var_dump($t3=getValue('un') ===  null);
 var_dump($t4=getValue('blablablaaaaaa') === null);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 bool(false)
 bool(true)
 // After the switch
 bool(false)
 bool(true)
```

This is not what I was expecting for the two first outputs, because the comparison is higher-precedence than assignment. So php should've tried to compare `null === $t1`, or `$t1` has not been declared yet, so a warning or error or whatever should've been raised. Or that didn't happen. **Do you notice that PHP sometimes treat assignment before comparison although comparison is higher-precedence and thus should always be performed before assignment?**. Any explanations about this?

My second question is: should this be avoided by always splitting up this kind of expression?

**UPDATE**

N.B

```
 var_dump($t1, $t2, $t3, $t4); 
 // OUTPUT

 int(1)
 NULL
 // After the switch
 bool(false)
 bool(true)
```

Comment: Interesting example, but regardless of the answer - IMO this style of code writing is bad because of poor readability (it's really not clear what you want it to do).
As far as why it happens - I'd guess the assignment goes first because comparison's right hand side should be determined to be compared against.

Comment: Every precedence question has at best academical interest. IRL - not sure? Place parenthesis!

Comment: @Kleskowy Don't agree with about the readability, because it's very common to check the value of a new variable immediately after the assignment.

Comment: Well, assigning to `null === $t1` obviously doesn't make sense. So `null === $a = $b` means *compare the result of the assignment to null*. However, `$a = $b === null` makes perfect sense as *assign the result of the comparison to `$a`.*

Comment: @AlmaDo lets place parenthesis everywhere then :D. I know that it's safer but It's more about either I didn't understand well this part of the documentation or it's not very clear

Comment: @deceze **So null === $a = $b means compare the result of the assignment to null**, this is not what's explained in the doc which says clearly that assignment is lower-precedence than comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`===` is  **non-associative**.

> [Non-associative operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity#Non-associative_operators) are operators that have no defined behavior when used in sequence in an expression.

And in [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

> `=` has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will still allow expressions similar to the following: if (!$a = foo()), in which case the return value of foo() is put into $a.

So it can be assumed `PHP` (in any of the expression) will first assign the return value of the function to the variable and then compare.

Comment: Please have a look at the update, before the switch `PHP` assigns and then compare, but after the switch it compares and then assigns the comparison result. Why doesn't PHP compare first as expected before and after the switch??

Comment: @smarber Updated the answer.

Comment: In The table which lists the operators in order of precedence I can see **=== is non-associative**. But if `===` has no precedence, why is it listed in the table and is above = (assignment) ?

Comment: **Note:
Although = has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will still allow expressions similar to the following: if (!$a = foo()), in which case the return value of foo() is put into $a.** .. `!` has more precedence than `=`. Read it their.